# Radar tiles for web map

Tags: openlayers, weather-api

I have an openlayers map which I want to display a radar animation on.  Currently I am using the weather underground api to download a single image for the United States.  I turn off and on 6 images about 15 minutes apart to create the animation. This image gets very blurry when you zoom in so it is not a good solution.  What I want are several tiles, that change when you zoom in so the radar is much clearer when you are zoomed in.  Can anyone recommend an api that provides radar tiles like I am describing that I can integrate into an openlayers map?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which technology are you using? With html and css you could create gradients and circle the gradient around.

Comment: I am using a combination of javascript, html, and css.  I am not following your advice though.  What I want is a radar animation something like this:  https://www.wunderground.com/wundermap/?units=english&rad=1&rad.num=1&rad.spd=25&rad.opa=81&rad.type=00Q&rad.type2=&rad.smo=1&rad.stm=0&sat=0&stormreports=0&svr=0&pix=0&cams=0&tor=0&riv=0&wxsn=0&ski=0&tfk=0&mm=0&ndfd=0&fire=0&firewfas=0&extremes=0&hurrevac=0&sst=0&livesurge=0&femaflood=0&tsunami=0&seismicrisk=0&fault=0&fissures=0&fronts=0&dir=1&dir.mode=driving&hur=0

Comment: Sry I do not know of any rain prediction api. Further more @tripleee told me that such questions are off topic: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.